# In case of fire, go to an open space/ground/field?

Tags: word-choice, american-english

As a general advice, when a building is in fire, people inside should go outside, and stay at an open space/ground/field.

Which word should I use?

Comment: "When a building is **on** fire." In the UK, public buildings usually have one or more designated 'assembly points' or 'areas' nearby, where people should gather when the fire alarm sounds.

Answer (score 1):

All three seem a little odd.  "Open space" is probably the least odd. It means "land that isn't used intensively" and would include parks, fields, woods, and undeveloped land in a city.  But do you really mean that the people should go to a park?

"Open ground" means land that is flat and free of buildings completely, right outside the city.  And open field would mean a flat agricultural terrain.

You don't actually need people to stay at an open space.  You want

> "Go outside and stay outside".

(It is okay to repeat "outside" for emphasis).  If you need to say that they can't stand close to the build that is on fire then

> "Go outside and stay away from the building".

If you need them to avoid all buildings (as might be advice after an earthquake.

> "Go outside and stay away from buildings".

If you have a specific place to go to, such as a park called "Kings Park":

> "Go outside and muster in Kings Park".

Comment: I want to emphasize an outside place that 1. we can see sky; 2. not very close to other buildings. How do I say that? Assume someone may count a narrow alley between two buildings outside.

Comment: Go outside and stay away from the building.  (Alleys are fine, provided they are not the alley next to the building, or so it seems to me)

Comment: Can you offer some synonyms? Assume now I'm a construction company, I'm planning a number of buildings, and I need to make sure between each buildings, "people can Go outside and stay away from the building (Alleys are fine, provided they are not the alley next to the building, or so it seems to me)" in case of fire.

Comment: You need to provide a designated assembly point (see my comment above).